# WPF rotate animation

Tags: wpf, rotation, rendertransform

I'm working with WPF and I can't achieve an animation.

I have a rectangle which rotates from x degree with a render transform origin from 0,0.
I want this rectangle to rotates from y degrees with a render transform origin from 0,1 after 2 seconds.

Of course I want to keep the rectangle position for the second animation.

My problem is when I change the rendertransform origin and apply the second rotation the current position is not kept and he moves from the initial location.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Thank's for helping.

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleMove"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="OpenWWindow" Height="900" Width="900">
  <Grid >
    <Rectangle Name="rec1" Width="100" Height="400" Fill="DimGray" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
      <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="Rec1_Rotate"/>
      </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>

    <Button Width="45" Height="30" Name="Button1">Start
      <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
          <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard TargetProperty="Angle">                
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Rec1_Rotate" By="40" Duration="00:00:1" BeginTime="00:00:00"/>                                                
                <PointAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rec1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransformOrigin" To="0,1" Duration="00:00:0" BeginTime="00:00:02" />
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Rec1_Rotate" By="-80" Duration="00:00:2" BeginTime="00:00:03"/>
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
      </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: There is something I don't quite understand about what you are trying to do. Could you explain a bit differently. From my understanding you are trying to rotate the rectangle by 40 to the left from the original point then you are moving the point to 0,1 and you want it to always rotate from there? Are you wanting it to rotate from a different corner of the rectangle for the second animation? Just looking for some clarification of the desired outcome.

Comment: I it's exactly that. I want to rotate from the first point with the first animation. And then move again from a different point, but keeping the precedent location. I hope it's clearer

Answer (score 2):

RenderTransformOrigin refers to the starting point of, in this case, the rectangle in the window. When you rotate based on point (0,0) the rectangle will rotate around the top left corner of itself. If you change the RenderTransformOrigin to now rotate around (0,1) you are not rotating now based on the bottom left corner of the rectangle in it's current position but you are rotating based on the original position of the rectangle. My thoughts on this would be to set the render transform origin to something like (0,0.5) to get the rocking motion you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you are looking for, I used Microsoft Expression Blend. Your anchor point was not in the correct location (i'm not sure if you are switching rotate points for each animation but this assumes you are rocking it back and forth.

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleMove"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="OpenWWindow" Height="900" Width="900">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="AnimateRectangle">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="40"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="-60"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource AnimateRectangle}"/>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource AnimateRectangle}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Comment: Sorry but I cant make your sample work. Could you give the entire code for the Window. I'm actually only using VS 2010