# How to make this circle with the arc inside on a Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-store, direct2d

In my Windows Store application, I'm looking a way to draw a circle (white) and then create a small arc (aqua) to make a dynamic arc rotating through the circle . Look at the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxqif.png

I started reading about Direct2D, but maybe that technology is too much for only this. I really feel at this situation to replicate this design in my application.

What do you recommend or how could you show an example for getting stated? To create the circle and rotate the arc through the circle

Answer (score 0):

You can use XAML to do this. For this you need to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786064/how-to-create-a-circle-with-a-hole-in-a-circle-in-wpf) to create the two "circles", the outer and the inner one. Then you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931406/wpf-rotate-animation) to let the inner circle/`Ellipse` spin arround using a `Storyboard`. You cannot use this code 1:1 because there are small differences between WPF XAML and Win8 XAML, but you should be able to use this in your project.